# How to localize tableView cells in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, localization

How to localize `TableView` cells in Swift?

For one String variable it's:

```
let alertTitle = NSLocalizedString("a", comment: "")
```

But how can I localize array for `TableView`?

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to localize each string separately as you do with with `alertTitle`. If you do not use the comment for the localized string (as most people do) you can simplify localization with an extension

```
extension String {

    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
    }

}
```

and define your array with

```
let array = ["a".localized, "b".localized, "c".localized, "d".localized, "e".localized]
```

or even shorter with

```
let let array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"].map({ $0.localized })
```

Comment: There is a serious problem with this approach - you can't use `genstrings` to generate the strings file from uses of `NSLocalizedString` in your code and you can't provide proper comments for each string.

Answer (score 2):

Using @sundance's String extension:

```
extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
    }
}
```

I would prefer using this extension over `[String]`:

```
extension Array where Element == String {
    var localized: [Element] {
        return self.map({ $0.localized })
    }
}
```

Then you can use this:

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"].localized
```

Comment: There is a serious problem with this approach - you can't use `genstrings` to generate the strings file from uses of `NSLocalizedString` in your code and you can't provide proper comments for each string.

Answer (score 1):

```
 let array = [NSLocalizedString("a", comment: ""), NSLocalizedString("b", comment: ""), NSLocalizedString("c", comment: ""), NSLocalizedString("d", comment: ""), NSLocalizedString("e", comment: "")]
```

some way I like when localizing group of related data

```
 let arrayLocalized = [string]()

 for i in 1...10
 {
   arrayLocalized.append(NSLocalizedString("a\(i)", comment: ""))

 }
```

where localization file looke like this

```
 "a1"="first value";

 "a2"="second value";

  .
  .
  .


 "a10"="last value";
```

Comment: There is a serious problem with the approach using a `for` loop - you can't use `genstrings` to generate the strings file from uses of `NSLocalizedString` in your code and you can't provide proper comments for each string.